# Does Apache support PHPIniDir on windows?

Tags: php, windows, apache

```
PHPIniDir "D:/Dev/PHP/"
```

The above instruction can make my apache die on windows.

But I'm just not sure if that's true.

BTW,I found xmpp/wampserver copies the php.ini to the directory of `httpd.exe`,maybe for the lack of support?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : yes, Apache does support PHPIniDir on Windows.

One thing you probably should look out for is whether the path to your extensions is correctly set in the php.ini you use, because if it's not Apache will not start. And if Apache doesn't start, then checking your Apache error log could be helpful to find the cause.

Comment: Then turn on PHP error logging and check the PHP error log for entries like "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'XXX.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: The unfound dll DOES exist,though,what's the matter?

Comment: Check your system path and make sure the extension dir that is specified in php.ini is correct. You should make sure that DLLs are somewhere in your path (also read the PHP docs and add the PHP folder to your system path as is mentioned there - http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php).