# apache not starting after adding php extension

Tags: php, apache

UGH - 
windows server 2003
apache 2.2 (httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8t)
PHP 5.2 (php-5.2.17-Win32-VC6-x86)

Everything has been humming along fine for months - I recently implemented a mPDF implementation...(locally developed on laptop)
when I uploaded it to my server - I got an error saying I needed PHP_MBSTRING

So I relaunched my installer on my server - and added this extension...
apache would not restart.

If I comment out THESE line from my http.conf - then it starts...

```
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

yes - php5apache2_2.dll DOES exist - and is in this directory...
I tried commenting out this extension PHP_MBSTRING and even removing it from the EXT folder...

I have tried fully uninstalling and reinstalling...
I have troed upgrading to PHP 5.3 (which required installing C++ redist)
and PHP 5.4 - although neither of these helped.

WTFlip!! Im at a loss -

ERROR LOG LIKE LIKE THIS:

```
Syntax error on line 520 of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'PHPIniDir', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue Feb 26 23:33:19 2013] [notice] Child 1492: Released the start mutex
[Tue Feb 26 23:33:20 2013] [notice] Child 1492: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Feb 26 23:33:20 2013] [notice] Child 1492: Child process is exiting
```

Comment: Comment out all extensions in (apache's) php.ini. Try to start apache. Does it start?

Comment: When it doesn't start, what does your `error_log` say?

Comment: Error log looks like this (added above as part of question):

Answer (score 1):

For one, forward slashes are correct. That is to say...

```
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Is the php directory in your path?

Also, make sure you've added

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

just before  in the conf file

Has PHP EVER been successfully running on this system and are you able to return to a working configuration? If so, you should be able to add the multi-byte string module from there.

Comment: yes - I tried the forward slash (as mentioned) and it has no effect...
and yes PHP was running for MONTHS before this....

Comment: Any possibility of permission issues?

Comment: maybe, but i wouldnt know where to look

Answer (score 0):

Here are a lists of solution related to that issue :

- [PHPIniDir broken under windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912574/phpinidir-broken-under-windows-7)

and also

- [Does Apache support PHPIniDir on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816704/does-apache-support-phpinidir-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 25 linux, you must load the module before using
the PHPIniDir attribute because the module provides the ability to read the attribute...yet...

using httpd 2.4.x (apache) and php 5.6.30 the server would not start when LoadModule php5_module ... and PHPIniDir "/etc" were in the same file under /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d  -- that stumped me for a while because the LoadModule directive did come before the PHPIniDir attribute...
go figure...

however, when the LoadModule command was in httpd.conf in the /etc/httpd/conf folder and the PHPIniDir attribute was set as above, then
everything works fine and phpinfo() confirms the loaded ini file is "/etc/php.ini"

so to conclude, this works for me:
in httpd.conf

LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

in conf.modules.d/10-php5.conf, at the end of the file

PHPIniDir "/etc"

---then of course restart apache "systemctl restart httpd" and
check phpinfo() on whatever web page you put it on..